# How To Calculate Length Of Sequences And A Suitable N?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, convolution, step-response

I have been struggling to understand how to calculate the length of a sequence and also the minimal N to choose in order to avoid aliasing.

Most sources tell me to take the (last non-zero value - first non-zero value + 1 = N)
In this case, I calculated the length of x1[n] to be (3-0+1) =4 and x2[n] to be (3-1+1) =3

And so N would be 4+3-1 = 6

However checking my professors working, he's gotten 4 for the length of both and N=7.Has he made a mistake or have I? And how do I actually go about solving part b?

[image]

I would be very grateful If I can get some help asap! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

$y[n]$ is the result of a linear convolution; the linear convolution of two sequences each with length 4 would be 4+4-1 = 7. If we don't extend the DFT's with zero padding to be at least this length, the result will be circular convolution (aliasing).

Comment: But isn’t the length of the second sequence 3 not 4? Or should I always extend each length to be a power of 2?

Comment: @Sugi The second sequence isn't `[1,2,1]` it's `[0,1,2,1]`. That extra sample of delay is important, so the statement `(last non-zero value - first non-zero value + 1 = N` is incorrect.  The second sequence is of length 4 because we usually think about sequence lengths of causal sequences, so they **must** start at index 0.  The incorrect statement could be correct if the first non-zero coefficient was before time zero (e.g. $\delta[n+1]$) as then you'd have to take into account the non-causal coefficients.  For causal sequences, the zero is the start coefficient (even if it is zero-valued).